# One or other required still shows an error

Tags: typescript

I checked a dozen related questions on SO with nothing pointing me to what I'm doing wrong.

```js
interface BaseProps {
  className?: string;
}

interface MessageOnly extends BaseProps {
  message: string;
  error?: never;
  input?: never;
}

interface ErrorAndInput extends BaseProps {
  message?: never;
  error: ErrorResponse;
  input: string;
}

type Props = MessageOnly | ErrorAndInput;
```

`error`:

```js
export interface ErrorResponse {
  message: string;
  errors: {
    [key: string]: string[];
  };
}

const [error, setError] = useState<ErrorResponse | null>(null);
```

`form` is an instance of [Inertia.js](https://inertiajs.com/) `useForm`. Not sure if that helps but don't know what else I can provide for `form` context:

```js
import { FormDataConvertible, Method, Progress, VisitOptions } from '@inertiajs/core';
type setDataByObject<TForm> = (data: TForm) => void;
type setDataByMethod<TForm> = (data: (previousData: TForm) => TForm) => void;
type setDataByKeyValuePair<TForm> = <K extends keyof TForm>(key: K, value: TForm[K]) => void;
type FormDataType = object;
export interface InertiaFormProps<TForm extends FormDataType> {
    data: TForm;
    isDirty: boolean;
    errors: Partial<Record<keyof TForm, string>>;
    hasErrors: boolean;
    processing: boolean;
    progress: Progress | null;
    wasSuccessful: boolean;
    recentlySuccessful: boolean;
    setData: setDataByObject<TForm> & setDataByMethod<TForm> & setDataByKeyValuePair<TForm>;
    transform: (callback: (data: TForm) => TForm) => void;
    setDefaults(): void;
    setDefaults(field: keyof TForm, value: FormDataConvertible): void;
    setDefaults(fields: Partial<TForm>): void;
    reset: (...fields: (keyof TForm)[]) => void;
    clearErrors: (...fields: (keyof TForm)[]) => void;
    setError(field: keyof TForm, value: string): void;
    setError(errors: Record<keyof TForm, string>): void;
    submit: (method: Method, url: string, options?: VisitOptions) => void;
    get: (url: string, options?: VisitOptions) => void;
    patch: (url: string, options?: VisitOptions) => void;
    post: (url: string, options?: VisitOptions) => void;
    put: (url: string, options?: VisitOptions) => void;
    delete: (url: string, options?: VisitOptions) => void;
    cancel: () => void;
}
export default function useForm<TForm extends FormDataType>(initialValues?: TForm): InertiaFormProps<TForm>;
export default function useForm<TForm extends FormDataType>(rememberKey: string, initialValues?: TForm): InertiaFormProps<TForm>;
export {};
```

`message` declaration:

```js
<FormError className="mt-2" message={form.errors.name} />
```

`message` error:

```
TS2322: Type
{   className: string;   message: string | undefined; } 

is not assignable to type

IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<Props>

Type

{   className: string;   message: string | undefined; }

is missing the following properties from type ErrorAndInput: error, input
```

`error, input` declaration:

```js
<FormError error={error} input="email" className="mt-2" />
```

`error, input` error:

```
TS2322: Type ErrorResponse | null is not assignable to type ErrorResponse | undefined

Type null is not assignable to type ErrorResponse | undefined

FormError.tsx(12, 3): The expected type comes from property error which is declared here on type

IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<Props>
```

Comment: You have neither shown us the declaration of the `FormError` component nor of the `form` and `error` variables, only their usages. We cannot help you without seeing the actual type declarations.

Comment: @Bergi not sure if that helps but I edited my post with the types of `error` and `form`. I'm pretty new to TypeScript and not very experienced in JS overall so please let me know if I can add more context.

Comment: The second error message suggests that `error` does not have the type `ErrorResponse` but rather the type `ErrorResponse | null`.

Comment: …and your edit showing the `const [error, …] = useState<…>(…)` declaration confirms that. You probably meant to put the `<FormError error={error} input="email" className="mt-2" />` inside a conditional block with `error != null`

Comment: I ended up simplifying my FormError component because I realized I did an absolute overkill for the required use case. Your comments helped point out the unnecessary complexity. Thank you.